# In Qt on Linux/X11, how do I fix main window ordering issue?

Tags: linux, qt, modal-dialog, x11

I've got a Qt application that has two main windows.  On Linux, when one main window brings up a modal dialog, it comes up behind the other main window.  What can I do to cause the dialog to always come up on top of ALL main windows?

NOTE: This only happens on Linux.  We build this app on MacOSX as well, and the problem does not occur there.

Here's the code that brings up the dialog.  The stuff in the #if is all the things I've tried to bring the window forward.  I've tried various combinations and orders of these things.

```
    QMessageBox dialog;
    dialog.setIcon( QMessageBox::Information );
    dialog.setWindowTitle( _documentName );
    dialog.setText( tr("This document has unsaved changes. Do you want to save before closing?") );
    dialog.setInformativeText( tr("Your changes will be lost if you don't save them.") );
    dialog.setStandardButtons( QMessageBox::Save | QMessageBox::Discard | QMessageBox::Cancel );
    dialog.setDefaultButton( QMessageBox::Save );
    dialog.setFixedSize( dialog.size() );   // non-resizable window
#if STUFF_I_TRIED
    dialog.show();
    dialog.setVisible(true);
    dialog.open();
    dialog.activateWindow();
    dialog.raise();
#endif
int result = dialog.exec();
```

I realize that exec() should be all I need to show the window.  My idea in calling show() or open() was just to allow activateWindow() or raise() to take affect.  Just foolin' around trying to get that damn dialog to come forward.

TIA for any help!

Comment: Sorry.  I had neglected to show the dialog.exec() call that I'm using to actually show the window.

PLEASE UNDERSTAND: The stuff in the #if is only for illustrative purposes to show the kinds of things I've been trying.  My understanding is that I should need none of these...that exec() should do all the right things.

Comment: Can you please provide code excerpt when and how two main windows are created? One of them should be parent anyway, right?

Comment: Andrejs, you're right!!!  That's it!  I missed the fact that this dialog had no parent.  When I pass the parent window to the dialog's constructor, all is well...the dialog then comes up over both windows.  I figured I might be missing something basic. Thanks much for giving my brain that kick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the sequcence between *#if 1_* and *#endif* looks pretty weird to me.
Normally, to show modal dialog, only [exec](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qmessagebox.html#exec)() is needed:

```
QMessageBox msgBox;
msgBox.setText("They killed Kenny, again.");
int ret = msgBox.exec();
```

[Reference](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qmessagebox.html#the-property-based-api).

Comment: Sorry.  You're absolutely right.  I wasn't clear on what the stuff in the #if was.  I've ammended the question text.

Comment: Andrejs gave me the clue that allowed me to fix this.  I wasn't passing the parent window into the dialog's constructor.  Doing that fixed the problem.  Andrejs mentioned this as a comment on the original question (see above), but I'll give him credit via this answer of his.   Thanks Andrejs!

Answer (score 0):

You are doing quite a bit of things between your #if 1, that is likely confusing X11.

You need only ONE of those. Since you are working with Mac and X11, I suspect you want to use open() and get a sheet.

IIRC, show() vs. open() causes different window flags to be set, so
calling them right after each other may get the window into a strange
state. Also calling show() or open() should always activate or raise the window if it is a dialog, which QMessageBox is.

Try only using one of these and seeing what happens.

Comment: Sorry that I wasn't clearer in my original formulation of the problem.  I have tried just calling show() or open(), but only in the hopes that they might cause the calls raise() or activateWindow() to have the desired affect.  My real code (outside the #if) had neither of these.